# mssql_num_row requires 1 parameter to be resourced

Tags: php, sql

Here is my code:

```
$link=mssql_connect($server, 'username','password');
if (!$link) {
die('Something went wrong while connecting to the mssql database, it could be offline! ' . mssql_get_last_message());
                                        }
                                        mssql_select_db('GunzDB', $link);
                                        $result="SELECT * FROM Account WHERE UserID = '$username'";

                                        if(mssql_num_rows($result) > 0){
                                            echo "That username is already in use!";    
                                    } else{
                                        $result="SELECT * FROM Account WHERE Email = '$email'";

                                        if(mssql_num_rows($result) > 0){
                                            echo "That email is already in use!";
                                        } else{

                                            $query="INSERT INTO Account (UserID, UGradeID, PGradeID, RegDate, Name, Email) VALUES ('" . $username . "','0','0','00:00','" . $name . "','" . $email . "')";
                                            if($query){
                                            $result="SELECT * FROM Account WHERE UserID = '$username'";

                                            $row = mssql_fetch_array($result);
                                            $AID=$row['AID'];
                                            $query="INSERT INTO Login (AID, Password) VALUES ('" . $AID . "','" . $password . "')";
                                            if($query){
                                            echo "<span style='color: lime'>Your account has been successfully created!</span>";
                                            } else{
                                                echo "error with MSSQL: " . mssql_get_last_message();
                                            }
                                            } else{
                                             echo "error with MSSQL: " . mssql_get_last_message();  
                                            }
```

I keep getting these errors
Warning: mssql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /var/www/gunz/register.php on line 81

Warning: mssql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /var/www/gunz/register.php on line 86

Warning: mssql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /var/www/gunz/register.php on line 94

it has to do with these rows

```
$result="SELECT * FROM Account WHERE UserID = '$username'";

$result="SELECT * FROM Account WHERE Email = '$email'";

$result="SELECT * FROM Account WHERE UserID = '$username'";
```

can I get some help?

Answer (score 0):

You're not **sending** the query to get a result.

```
$result = mssql_query("SELECT ... ");
```

You're also vulnerable to SQL injection. Read up on using binded parameters and prepared statements.

[See the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-query.php)